# Mock DB for IDB DB2 in NodeJs

Tags: node.js, mocking, mocha.js

I am creating test cases for my nodejs application using mocha.

My question is: 
Are the any available tools/resource that allows me to create a mock DB for IBM DB2 in nodejs?

I do not wish to writing data into the development DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is. Try https://sinonjs.org/ for mocking the database functions.